# make pointing arrow at the end of the drawing canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, turtle-graphics

I created a Javascript program, with turtle graphics, and I would like to know how to put a pointing triangle (or any shape) at the end of each drawing so I can choose which side the drawing can be oriented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>HTML5 canvas turtle graphics</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  canvas {border: 1px dotted #564b47;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML5 canvas turtle graphics</h1>

<canvas id="myDrawing" width="600" height="300"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

"use strict";
// JavaScript statements
// =====================================================================================
var color = {
    black: "#ffffff",
    red: "#ff0000",
    green: "#00ff00",
    blue: "#0000ff",
    yellow: "#ffff00",
    fuchsia: "#ff00ff",
    aqua: "#00ffff"
};

var turtle = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    angleInRadians: 0,
    penDown: false,
    penColor: "#000000",
    lineWidth: 2
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');

if (canvas && canvas.getContext) { // does the browser support 'canvas'?
    turtle.ct = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get drawing context
} else {
    alert('You need a browser which supports the HTML5 canvas!');
}

// =====================================================================================


turtle.logPenStatus = function () {
    console.log('x=' + this.x + "; y=" + this.y + '; angle = ' + this.angle + '; penDown = ' + this.penDown);
};


turtle.forward = function (length) {
    // console.log('forward(' + length + ')');
    // this.logPenStatus();
    var x0 = this.x,
        y0 = this.y;
    this.x += length * Math.sin(this.angleInRadians);
    this.y += length * Math.cos(this.angleInRadians);
    if (this.ct) {
        if (this.penDown) {
            //this.logPenStatus();
            this.ct.beginPath();
            this.ct.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            this.ct.strokeStyle = this.penColor;
            this.ct.moveTo(x0, y0);
            this.ct.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
            this.ct.stroke();
        }
    } else {
        this.ct.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    }
    return this;
};

turtle.backward = function (length) {
    this.forward(-length);
    return this;
};

turtle.left = function (angleInDegrees) {
    // console.log('left(' + angleInDegrees + ')');
    // A complete circle, 360º, is equivalent to 2? radians  
    // angleInDegrees is an angle measure in degrees
    this.angleInRadians += angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return this;
};

turtle.right = function (angleInDegrees) {
    this.left(-angleInDegrees);
    return this;
};


turtle.angle = function () {
    // the turtle status is hold in this.angleInRadians;
    // degrees are often more convenient for the display
    return this.angleInRadians * 180.0 / Math.PI;

};
```

for example here is a simple drawing

```
turtle.x = 50;       // the x-axis of the pen
turtle.y = 100;      // the y-axis of the pen
turtle.penDown = true;
 turtle.forward(50);
    turtle.left(150);
    turtle.forward(7);
    turtle.backward(7);
    turtle.right(150);
    turtle.right(150);






</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the x/y where you want the arrow and the radian angle of your “turtle”, you can draw an arrowhead like this:

```
function drawArrowhead(x,y,radians){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(5,20);
    ctx.lineTo(-5,20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

This puts the tip of the arrowhead at x/y and rotated to the radian angle specified.

You can experiment with the exact placing of the arrowhead (on-endpoint, after-endpoint, etc) and with the shape of your arrowhead.